# Concatenate String in Python

Tags: python

I am looking to create a string of all errors returned from the API. There may be multiple errors returned in a list. Each error is a dict and the string I wish to access its the reason:

```
  result: {
       errors: [{
          error: 'invalid_input',
          code: 409,
          reason: 'the inputted date field does not match required format'

       },
       {
          error: 'invalid_input',
          code: 409,
          reason: 'the inputted message field does not match required format'
        }

  }
```

What I have tried is:

```
return_string = ""
if errors in result:
    for error in errors:
        returned_string += " {}".format(error['reason'])
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: returned_string += " {}".format(error['reason')

Comment: return_string* ?

Answer (score 4):

There are several typos in your code. But the more Pythonic way would be with a <s>list comprehension</s> generator expression:

```
return_string = ""
if "errors" in result:
    return_string = " ".join(error['reason'] for error in result['errors'])
```

Or even in one line:

```
return_string = " ".join(error['reason'] for error in result.get('errors', []))
```

Comment: you mean a generator expression, no list comprehensions here

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {
       "errors": [{
          "error": 'invalid_input',
          "code": 409,
          "reason": 'the inputted date field does not match required format'

       },
       {
          "error": 'invalid_input',
          "code": 409,
          "reason": 'the inputted message field does not match required format'
        }]

  }

return_string = ""
if result.get("errors", None):
    for error in result["errors"]:
        return_string += " {}\n".format(error['reason'])
print return_string
```

**Output:**

```
the inputted date field does not match required format
 the inputted message field does not match required format
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) along with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to fetch the `reason` key from your list of dicts like

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> error_list = list(map(itemgetter('reason'),r['errors']))
```

This will give you output like

```
>>> ['the inputted date field does not match required format', 'the inputted message field does not match required format']
```

Next you can use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join these strings together as one error message

```
>>> "".join(error_list)
>>> 'the inputted date field does not match required formatthe inputted message field does not match required format'
```

You can also specify the character on which you want seperate these two string

```
>>> " ".join(error_list) #Whitespace
>>> 'the inputted date field does not match required format the inputted message field does not match required format'
```

If you prefer one-liners

```
>>> " ".join(map(itemgetter('reason'),r['errors']))
```